# Cannot start audio only connection on react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc, sip, jssip

I’m using JsSIP and react-native-webrtc for audio only communication. I’ve managed to start session and get remote and local stream objects. Our SIP server converts voip calls to a normal phone call. I know I successfully start session because I can call my own phone number and answer it.

Since I can’t use RTCView I can’t play audio. And since there is no audio transmitting, server gives a time out after a while and stops session, and phone hangs up. How can I start sending and receiving sound?

Comment: Why can't you use RTCView? It can play MediaStreams with only audio.

Comment: Isn't it dedicated to video stream? I don't need any view actually. So I didn't even try it.

Comment: Hi can I know how you able to work JsSip with React-Native-WebRTC? Thank you